# Filter out the odd one out from an array, then return the index position

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, filter

I have an array of the same word however one of the words in the array is spelt backwards. The function returns the index position of the "wrong" word.  The below code works perfectly fine but it is quite long.

I want to know if there is a way to shorten the code and still have it return the same value?

```
function oddOneOut(arr) {

  let word = ''

  if (arr[0] === arr[1]) {
    word = arr[0]
  }
  if (arr[1] === arr[2]) {
    word = arr[1]
  }
  if (arr[2] === arr[3]) {
    word = arr[2]
  }
  function wrong(element) {
    return element !== word
  }
  return arr.findIndex(wrong)
}

console.log(oddOneOut(["sword", "sword", "sword", "sword", "drows", "sword"]))

//returns 4
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! At first glance, I'd say your `oddOneOut()` function could be improved by using a `for` loop -- it looks rather hard-coded at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is only one item that will be different, you can just check each item against the one before and one after it, and if it is different than each one return that index.

```
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  let previous = i - 1;
  let next = i + 1;

  if(i == array.length - 1) {
    next = 0;
  }

  if(array[i] != array[previous] && array[i] != array[next]) {
    return i;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the ternary operator for your ifs and an in-built array function to find your odd word.

Here is an example :

```
function oddOneOut(arr) {
  let word = arr[0] === arr[1] ? arr[0] : arr[1] === arr[2] ? arr[1] : arr[0];
  return arr.findIndex(r => r !== word);
}

console.log(oddOneOut(["sword", "drows", "sword", "sword", "sword", "sword"]));
```

I hope this works for you.